# UWP: Set both background color and image?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

In a universal windows app, I need to set both background color and image (with some transparency) for a border element.

How can I create a brush that contains both? I have unsuccessfully tried using the Compositor class. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can't with current border element. But it's not hard to achieve same goal with alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've been doing with that brushes, but you could just place the `Grid` above an `Image` and set an `Opacity` property of the `Grid` to value between `0.0` (hidden) and `1.0` (fully visible).

```
<Image Source="Assets/YourImage" />
<Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.5">
    <!-- Your code here -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: You could use that or use an `ImageBrush` with `Opacity`. Or specify the opacity on whatever element is painted with your brush. If you have an irregular shape that you want painted with these combined brushes - you might need to use two shapes instead.

Comment: I don't need opacity. I have opaque PNG with some transparent areas that should go on top of another object with color.

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding the image with border helps in getting the background color in image.

```
<Border Background="Gray">
<Image Stretch="Fill" /></Border>
```